# Working with IViewLocationExpander in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to render views from a custom location, so for that I have implemented the 
`IViewLocationExpander` interface in a class. I have registered the same class in `Startup` class as follows.

**`Startup` Class**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    … 
    //Render view from custom location.
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CustomViewLocationExpander());
    });
    … 
}
```

**`CustomViewLocationExpander` Class**

```cs
public class CustomViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {

        var session = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SessionServices>();
        string folderName = session.GetSession<string>("ApplicationType");

        viewLocations = viewLocations.Select(f => f.Replace("/Views/", "/" + folderName + "/"));


        return viewLocations;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

And, finally, my application’s views are organized as follows:

[image: View folder structure]

My issue: If I access the `Views/Login` view from the `ViewsFrontend` folder from the following URL:

```
http://localhost:56739/trainee/Login/myclientname
```

But then immediately change the URL in the browser to:

```
http://localhost:56739/admin/Login/myclientname
```

In this case, it still refers to the `ViewsFrontend` folder, even though it *should* now refer to the `ViewsBackend` folder, since URLs beginning with `trainee` should refer to the `ViewsFrontend` folder, while those beginning with `admin` should refer to the `ViewsBackend` folder.

Further, after changing the URL in the browser, it only calls the `PopulateValues()` method, but not the `ExpandViewLocations()` method.

How can I reconfigure this class to work for this other folder?

Comment: Works fine with net 5.0, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PopulateValues` exists as a way to specify parameters that your view lookup would vary by on a per-request basis. Since you're not populating it, *the view engine uses cached values from an earlier request*.

To solve this, add your `ApplicationType` variable to the `PopulateValues()` method and the `ExpandValues()` method should get called whenever that value changes:

```
public class CustomViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        string folderName = context.Values["ApplicationType"];
        viewLocations = viewLocations.Select(f => f.Replace("/Views/", "/" + folderName + "/"));

        return viewLocations;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        var session = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SessionServices>();
        string applicationType = session.GetSession<string>("ApplicationType");
        context.Values["ApplicationType"] = applicationType;
    }
}
```