# Is it possible to have multiple layout pages in a C# razor application?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Previously I have created C# applications using MVC and it is possible to specify the layout view to use on the view in it's file. Such that the view file contains:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

/*Rest of file*/
```

Recently I have started creating applications using razor pages. So far I only have a single layout page. However, I would like to use a different layout page for a subset of pages, and I can only see how to specify a single layout page for all pages within the Pages folder. As the layout is declared in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. Where the contents of this file is simply:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Is there a way of using one layout file for some pages, and then a different layout files for other pages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870298/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-in-the-asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: This looks like it changed from .Net Framework to .Net Core, is that right? Rather than MVC & Razor? I switched from .Net Framework MVC to .Net Core Razor in one go, so I'm not always sure which part changed where.

Comment: It does appear to have changed.  I would focus on the answer in that post provided by @Sanket.  That approach makes the most sense to me.  Your mileage may vay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to `using one layout file for some pages, and then a different layout files for other pages`.you can try to get the current url in _ViewStart.cshtml,then check the url and set Layout page.Here is a demo:

_ViewStart.cshtml(Page1 and Page2 will set `Layout = "_Layout";`,and the other page will set `Layout = "_Layout1";`):

```
@{
    var routeUrl = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Page"].ToString();
    //you can put pages' name into pages
    var pages = new List<string> { "Page1", "Page2"};
    //if routeUrl contains any of pages,the page will use _Layout as Layout page,the other pages will use _Layout1 ad Layout page
    if (pages.Any(routeUrl.Contains))
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
    else {
        Layout = "_Layout1";
    }

}
```

result:
[image]

Also,you can use

```
@{
   Layout="xxx"
}
```

to set diiferent layout in different pages as `David Tansey` said.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for. Nice and simple to implement.

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. Even if you've registered single layout in ViewStart.cshtml you can still use different layout on specific page like:

   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
2. You can use either ViewData or ViewBag to assign the layout value and use that in your cshtm file
3. You can add a check to identity which layout you need to use:

.....

```
@{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        Layout = "_AdminLayout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
}
```