# The view 'Edit' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to edit blogs. I have Edit view in View folder in BlogAdmin folder.

```
 <a  href="/BlogAdmin/Edit/@item.id" class=" btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right"> Edit </a>
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
         {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        List<Blog> EditBg = db.Blogs.Where(i => i.id==id).ToList();
        if (EditBg== null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var vm = new VmBlog
        {
            blogcatg = db.BlogCategories.ToList(),
            Blog = db.Blogs.Where(i => i.id == id).ToList(),
            Content=db.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.id==id).posttext

        };

        return View(vm);

    }
```

Get method is working. There is no error here:
[image]

Everything seems correctly. But I am getting this error:

The view 'Edit' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

~/Views/BlogAdmin/Edit.aspx

~/Views/BlogAdmin/Edit.ascx

~/Views/Shared/Edit.aspx

~/Views/Shared/Edit.ascx

~/Views/BlogAdmin/Edit.cshtml

~/Views/BlogAdmin/Edit.vbhtml

~/Views/Shared/Edit.cshtml

~/Views/Shared/Edit.vbhtml

Why does error happen?

Comment: You sure your view isn't simply missing?

Comment: Yes. I have Edit view in the same folder with the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Microsoft documentation on Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1), specifically the section about [View Discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-discovery)

> It doesn't matter if you implicitly return the ViewResult with return View(); or explicitly pass the view name to the View method with return View("");. In both cases, view discovery searches for a matching view file in this order:
>
> Views/[ControllerName]/[ViewName].cshtml
>
> Views/Shared/[ViewName].cshtml

It seems that your folder structure does not account for the specified view discovery

If you want to change the folder structure and View discovery

> You can customize the default convention for how views are located within the app by using a custom [IViewLocationExpander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

A very nice answer on this, can be found [Working with IViewLocationExpander in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471627/working-with-iviewlocationexpander-in-mvc)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But Edit view is located in the same folder in BlogAdmin folder.

Comment: If it's in the same folder with the controller, then it makes sense for the engine not to find it.

Comment: So what should i do is what you said in this answer?

Comment: Yeap. You need to migrate the Views, or implement an IViewLocationExpander. I would go with the first, simpler solution.

Comment: I think I did not ask question properly. I have Edit view in View folder in BlogAdmin folder. When i changed `<a href="/BlogAdmin/Edit/@item.id"> Edit </a>` to `<a href=" @Url.Action("Edit", "BlogAdmin", new { id = item.id })" > Edit </a>` it finds edit view

Answer (score 1):

@Aytac,

In the MVC pattern the default routing puts controllers into a folder at "/controllers".  Views are stored in a folder at "/Views/{ControllerBaseName}/{ActionName}".

The default folder structure (routing) should look like the following (tagged as c# so assuming c# extensions):

/Controllers/BlogAdminController.cs

/Views/BlogAdmin/Edit.cshtml

Comment: I think I did not ask question properly. I have Edit view in View folder in BlogAdmin folder. When i changed `<a href="/BlogAdmin/Edit/@item.id"> Edit </a>` to `<a href=" @Url.Action("Edit", "BlogAdmin", new { id = item.id })" > Edit </a>` it finds edit view.

Comment: Would you check the generated HTML of the link of your view in your browser?  What does it contain?  Is @item.id being correctly replaced with a number?

Comment: https://localhost:44348/BlogAdmin/Edit/7  is with this code `<a href="/BlogAdmin/Edit/@item.id"> Edit </a>` . And https://localhost:44348/HMadeAdmin/BlogAdmin/Edit/7 is with the razor syntax.