# How to start NET Core site with two separate library - Code and View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two separate project with NET CORE 6. One project contains all code - Controller, Models and so on. Other projects contains all View. Of course View has reference to code and Inject various data from Model to View.
This is output of View (class library) project (with references to Code project).

[image: class library project with View]

And this is output of Code project (Console application) with EntryPoint, tuning services in DI container and so on.

[image: output of Code project]

Of course, if we try to start Code project without View we will receive, because this project know nothing about View

> ```
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
> ```

And, of course, if we try to start project with View we will receive

> Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not
> defined.

Because this project know nothing about Entry Point, tuning services, DI container and so on.
Solution is something close, but I can not understand it, sorry. How is possible to start this web site?

Comment: If you want to separate your concerns in this way I believe you need a third project. Your main project will reference the View project _and_ the third project, and the View project will refrerence the third project as well. This way you can put code that is shared between your main project and View project in the third project to prevent circular dependencies. You should then be able to start your main project, which has a reference to your View project. In any case, you need to rethink your project structure.

Comment: You should use [IViewLocationExpander Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander?view=aspnetcore-6.0). For example see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39471627/5045688

Comment: thank for both advice. Will be try.

Comment: I'm with GT and that you need to review your structure. View and model separation is fine but there is a runtiminess wrapper that needs to tie them all together. This is issue is that you don't have a central binder of these two libraries to bring them together. Normally what's done is you have say a project that has rudimentary view structures and another has models. These are then included as dependencies in another project that implements the views (or extensions of them) along with the models. You need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see my final solution there https://github.com/Alex-1557/SplitViewAndCodeInAsp.Net.Core.Project

[image]

For connect static files to root I have rebuilded this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CeciliaWiren-CeciliaSHARP.FolderToSolutionFolder

for Visual Studio 2022 - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexev14.AddFolderToSolutionForVS2022